# Long running query plus rename table contention in MySQL brought down database. How to avoid?

Tags: mysql

We have a daily process by which we load data on a daily basis into our production MySQL database to our ‘staging’ tables (a set of MySQL tables residing on a staging schema).  Once the load of this data is complete, we make it live by the following process:

```
rename table myschema_live.customer to myschema_staging.tmp_customer
rename table myschema_staging.customer to myschema_live.customer
rename table myschema_staging.tmp_customer to myschema_staging.customer
```

This works great for us.  However, we recently encountered a fatal flaw in this process whereby a long running select query prevented the rename from happening which then took down our database.  There are some 30 tables involved here and the sql commands we run attempt to rename all 30 tables in one transaction.

I’m guessing the long running select query prevented one of the rename commands from acquiring a lock on the table to carry out the rename.  Meanwhile the rest of the rename transaction did acquire locks on the other tables preventing other queries from running.  Then the entire database is then waiting on the long running select to finish.  Does this sound right?

So my questions are:

1. How can we avoid this scenario from happening?
2. Is it possible to have the sql command (executed via a shell script via the mysql command) timeout if it waits more than a certain amount of time?
3. Is there a better way to acquire locks on the tables for this renaming purpose?
4. Is it possible to programmatically look for long running queries and not run the rename script if found?

Any thoughts most welcome.

We're using MySQL 5.7 with InnoDB.

Comment: *we run attempt to rename all 30 tables in one transaction.* RENAME TABLE causes immediate implicit commit. Transaction makes no sense in your process. *This works great for us.* It was random. Schema altering needs in most cases to prevent any external access to the table under change. The best way is to disable access to the table for any user another from the admin which will perform the operation.

Comment: So disabling autocommit (`SET autocommit=0;`) has no effect? We've been using this pattern for years and only encountered an issue with the long running queries.  These are live tables used by thousands of customers at all times.  We need a way to swap the tables around to get our data live without loss of connectivity.

Comment: *So disabling autocommit (SET autocommit=0;) has no effect?* Of course.

Comment: *We need a way to swap the tables around to get our data live without loss of connectivity.* I understand that replace "old version" data with "new version" seems to be the most simple... Imagine that you decide to use data update (remove+add+update). Does this process will be long and costly?

Comment: And. As I understand this database is accessed by users using some server-side application/script, is it? If so think about the variant: you put new  table near the old one, then you alter your application configuration and change tablename it must use. All clients deals with the data after this moment will access new data. Now you check is old tables accessed, and when all those processes finished you simply delete old tables.

Comment: Every night we're loading over 1 billion rows to the staging tables which takes a long time as you can imagine, so a data remove/add/update process won't work for us.  The database is accessed by around 20 different web applications over jdbc.  I think it would be difficult to automate the application datasources to swap to new tables, which might necessitate restarting said applications which wouldn't be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up taking multiple actions to address our issues.

1. We implemented a query against the `information_schema.processlist` table to identify long running queries prior to running our rename statements.  If any long running query was identified, then we error out the renames and force manual recovery.  Our query:

`select id, user, db, state, info, time from information_schema.processlist where id = (select id from information_schema.processlist where command='Query' order by time desc limit 1)`

We then check for `time` being greater than 60 seconds and cancel the rename if this condition is true.

2. We changed the [lock_wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lock_wait_timeout) value from its default of 1 year to 60 seconds.  This variable affects the time any query will wait to acquire a metadata lock on a table, after which it will timeout.  Thus, if our rename statements, which require a metadata lock, wait more than 60 seconds then the rename statement will fail.
3. Not directly related, but we also moved our rename statements to be a single transaction so that all rename statements succeed or all fail as opposed to our original process where some might complete and others were pending.  From this:

```
rename table myschema_live.customer to myschema_staging.tmp_customer;
rename table myschema_staging.customer to myschema_live.customer;
rename table myschema_staging.tmp_customer to myschema_staging.customer;
<repeat these rename statements for 29 other tables>
```

to

```
rename table myschema_live.customer to myschema_staging.tmp_customer,
       table myschema_staging.customer to myschema_live.customer,
       table myschema_staging.tmp_customer to myschema_staging.customer,
       <add 29 more tables worth of renames here>;
```